# Let $\Sigma$ be a maximal consistent set of formulas. Prove that |mod($\Sigma$)|= 1

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

I know the definition of maximal consistent set of formulas, but until now I cannot see how to use the definitions to prove that there only exists one model of any maximal consistent set $\Sigma$.
Maybe we have to use the fact that $\Sigma$ is the set of all its syntactic consequences or we just have to imagine two different models of $\Sigma$ and prove that they are the same one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\Sigma$ is maximal consistent then for all $\varphi$ either $\Sigma\vDash\varphi$ or $\Sigma\vDash \neg\varphi$.

Now consider $\varphi$ of the form $p_i$ where $p_i$ is a propositional variable and remember that in propositional logic a model is just a truth valuation.

Comment: So we have that for any formula A, A $\in \Sigma$ or $\neg A \in \Sigma$. Then if we have a valuation $\rho$ and $\rho$(A)=1 then A $\in \Sigma$, and if  $\rho$(A)=0 then $\neg A \in \Sigma$. But I still don't understand how to prove that  $\rho$ is unique.

Comment: @Rebe a valuation is determined by its value on the propositional variables